# C / Generate a random number between 1 to 4 leaving 3 out with arc4random( )?

Tags: iphone, c, ios, ipad, random

I have

```
int y = (arc4random()%4)+1;
```

So it generates a random number from 1 to 4.

I wanted to ask if there's a way to leave number 3 out so only numbers 1, 2 and 4 have a chance to get generated.

Thank you!

Comment: do it in a loop until it generates a number that ISN'T 3?

Comment: @MarcB: That could take arbitrarily long.

Comment: The execution time of a loop that breaks on a random number is indefinite and it adds unnecessary indeterminism.

Comment: Why is 3 bad?  Are you sure you're [trying to solve the right problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/164291)

Answer (score 9):

```
int allowdNumbers[3] = {1, 2, 4}
int index = arc4random()%3;

int number = allowdNumbers[index];
```

Comment: I would do this: `int index = arc4random_uniform(sizeof(allowdNumbers)/sizeof(int));`. You can also use `int allowdNumbers[] = {1, 2, 4};` without the `3`.

Answer (score 9):

You can always make a random from 0-2 (`arc4random() % 3`) and use that number with 2 as a power:

```
2^0 = 1
2^1 = 2
2^2 = 4
```

and there you got your random from 1-4 without 3.  In C:

```
int y = 1 << (arc4random() % 3);
```

Comment: The good with this is that you don't need any other structure to help you get the random number you need or any other logical checks. A simple math calculation.

Comment: This is a good solution, but I think JustSid's is better since it is easier to understand that you are selecting a random number from a specific range of allowed numbers rather than simply playing around with a random number to arrive at a result.

Comment: ... and the bad thing is that in each call of random(...) you will have a raise_to_power(...) op which in general is expensive.

Comment: 0x69: I hope you're joking... for integer powers of 2, you can just bitshift the integer rather than using `pow` or `powf`, and bitshifting is typically a very cheap operation.

Comment: I mean speed compared to @JustSid solution - dereferencing pointer should be faster than calculating power of 2, or am I wrong ?

Comment: @0x69: You are wrong. 2^n is `1 << n` which is a single instruction normally (and for small numbers).

Comment: Yup, one could just bitshift instead and I would think the bitshift would be better in this case only as it won't have to create the array for it, reserve memory and allocate it.

It all depends how it is stored as well. But I'd prefer bitshift it rather than using an array, for this case where it can be calculated though.

Comment: @dreamlax It is true JustSid's solution is easier to understand and is applicable in much more cases than this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a random number from 0 to the number of different numbers you have (exclusive, and in your case, 3), and distribute the result according to your preference. In your case:

```
int y = (rand() % 3) + 1;

if (y == 3)
    y++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want numbers that correspond to powers of two, then this should work nicely.

```
int y = 1 << arc4random_uniform(3);
```

If you want to leave out 3 for some other reason, then that would probably to more to obfuscate what you are doing than. In that case, something more straightforward would suffice.

```
do {
    int y = arc4random_uniform(4) + 1;
} while (y == 3);
```

Comment: That loop is not a good idea at all. Loops that run indefinitely waiting for a random number to occur are rarely (if at all) a good idea.

Comment: In general, yes. If this particular loop that filters out one of four possibilities is a problem, then you need a new random function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
int y = (arc4random()%3)+1;
if (y == 3) y =4;
```

Though you should arc4random_uniform instead of the modulo operator.

Comment: This isn't truly random then, because there will be a greater amount of "4"'s being generated, as both values "3" and "4" will be changed to "4".

Comment: @qegal look more closely. The first line will *never* make `y` equal 4.

Comment: @daknøk - Sorry; I guess I just skimmed over it.